# Using an array of ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. In my scenario, the user has to create a mcq question. The question has 4 default option and one of the options is correct. Now the user who is teacher can give greater or less then 4 options for the question. So its a variable number of options. If hard code the input as follow

```
<input name = "input0" type = "text", class = "form-control" ng-model = "input_0" required>

<input name = "input1" type = "text", class = "form-control" ng-model = "input_1" required>
```

and so on it works good. I want to use dynamic solution here, so it does not matter how many options the teacher provide.

What I was trying to do is

1. $scope.mcq_options = [$scope.input_0,$scope.input_1 ...]
2. use ng-repeat in html template and do something like

   ```
   <div ng-repeat = "input in mcq_options">
   <input name = "input1" type = "text", class = "form-control" ng-model = "input" required>
   ```
3. For removing splice entry from array
4. For adding more push entry in array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is quite straightforward ([**Associated PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/hI0sFPd4DzyhJTSLatIZ?p=preview)):

**[1](http://plnkr.co/edit/hI0sFPd4DzyhJTSLatIZ?p=preview)** Create an empty array that you may store all your options, in your controller.

```
var inputArray = $scope.inputArray = [];
```

**[2]** Create a function to add new options.

```
$scope.addNewOption = function() {
   inputArray.push('');
};
```

**[3]** Create another function to splice an option entry that accepts the index of an option to remove.

```
$scope.removeOption = function(index) {
  inputArray.splice(index, 1);
};
```

**[4]** Your view can be something like this:

```
    <form name="form" novalidate>
      <div ng-repeat="input in inputArray track by $index" ng-form="subform">
        <input name="input" type="text" ng-model="inputArray[$index]" required> <button ng-click="removeOption($index)">Remove</button>
        <br>
        <span ng-show="subform.input.$error.required">This field is rqeuired</span>
      </div>
      <button ng-click="addNewOption()">Add New Option</button>
    </form>
```

Note:

- The `track by $index` in the `ng-repeat` directive helps in avoiding duplicate values error.
- The `ng-form` directive helps you in validating each models that is created in every `ng-repeat` iteration.
- Instead of using the `input` value in the `ng-repeat` directive, use its direct reference by using the ng-repeat's `$index` property. If you dont't do this, changes in the inputArray may affect the current `ngModel` reference of your inputs. e.g. adding or removing options will give you weird behaviours.